# Checking if a string is substring of another string separated by commas using regex [Perl]

Tags: regex, string, perl

I would like to use regex in order to check if a string is a substring of another string but with an additional rule: the main string includes commas, so the substring should be one of the strings separated by commas.

It will be easier to explain using an example:

```
my $main_str = "   hello   ,how,   are, you";
my $sub1 = "hello";
my $sub2 = "how";
my $sub3 = "hello1";
```

For `$sub1` and `$sub2` the output should say - "found in the string".

For `sub3` it should say - "didn't find in the string".

You can assume that `$sub` contains the only alphabet `a-Z` with no special symbols (or whitespaces).

Consider the following regex:

```
@arr = ($main =~ /[^\s,]+/g);
```

With this regex, I can split the `$main` string into an array by commas without whitespaces. I could iterate over the array and check if one of them is `$sub` but it will require an additional function/loop to do so - meaning it's doesn't look very nice. I would like to solve this problem with beautiful regex rather than a loop.

Is it possible to create a regex similar to the one above, which checks if a string is a substring of another string which separated by commas and no whitespaces included?

Comment: The commas are irrelevant. What's wrong with `$main_string =~ /\b$sub1\b/`?

Answer (score 3):

Just separate the substrings with `|` and say it must be preceded by the very beginning or a comma, and followed by the very end or a comma. One of these must be a look-around assertion, as the comma ending one sub might be the comma starting another sub:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $main_str = "   hello   ,how, are, you ";
my @subs = qw( hello how hello1 you );

my $re = join '|', @subs;

say $1 while $main_str =~ /(?:^|,)\s*($re)\s*(?=,|$)/g;
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how frequently you're checking those matches, and how many... it may  *potentially* be faster to put the words in a hash for quick look-ups

```
my $main_str = "   hello   ,how,   are, you";

my %words = map { $_ => 1 } $main_str =~ /\w+/g;

for my $sub (qw( hello how hello1 )) {
    printf( "%8s : %s\n", $sub, $words{$sub} ? "Found" : "Not found" );
}
```

OUTPUT

```
   hello : Found
     how : Found
  hello1 : Not found
```

I know this isn't really an answer to your question (so don't accept this answer!). Just offerring a possible alternative.